# bootstrap carousel not hiding other element and showing all in the same time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGMRV.png)

[image: result]

I'm wondering why it will show all element in the same time, normally it should  start at the first element.

Am I done something stupid thing to make the tragedy?

Comment: Hi, please create [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could actually see the problem.

Comment: don't add image of code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you didn't import bootstrap correct.
Make sure you imported bootstrap.min.css, because bootstrap.min.js is not enough to render carousel and other components correct.